# Problem in hosting ActiveX on Vista (in a Visual Studio 6 C++ application)

Tags: visual-c++, com, windows-vista, activex, atl

I just installed Visual Studio 6 (SP5) on a Vista Enterprise machine. Had some problems but I think it’s set up alright.

The problem is my VC++ 6 application fails when trying to host an ActiveX.
I was able to compile it ok, though got a warning message from Vista about the rc.exe (“This program has known compatibility issues” ).

When I debugged it I saw that my class that derives from CAxDialogImpl fails on its Create() method.
The same application worked just fine on XP!

Is there a known compatibility issue there?

Some tech info:
I saw that CAxDialogImpl::Create() (I pass NULL here) calls AtlAxCreateDialogA, which in turn calls CreateDialogIndirectParamA which throws a general exception.

Thanks a lot,
Erik

PS - I am Admin on my machine. OS is 32 bit.

Comment: Why do you need to still use VS6?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this could be caused by Vista's DEP and the fact that it's hardwired to recognize ATL thunking code, but only of newer versions...?

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948468, for example.

Let me know if that works out.