# Browser keep stopping with user breakpoint and opens visual studio 6 in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, browser, windows-vista

Following my last question (see: [Problem in hosting ActiveX on Vista (in a Visual Studio 6 C++ application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184175/problem-in-hosting-activex-on-vista-in-a-visual-studio-6-c-application)) I ran into a strange problem. I hope this’ll be a simpler issue to the experts here:

Each time I run certain application like iexplorer or firefox, the Visual Studio 6 suddenly opens up in debug mode with a message “User breakpoint called from code at 0xSOMETHING”.
I can press F5 to continue but the applications run slowly and needless to say I have no wish to debug these applications…

My guess is that when I worked on my VC++ application I placed breakpoints at windows methods like CAxDialogImpl::Create(), AtlAxCreateDialogA() etc’, and for some reason it was kept somewhere.

Of course I now removed all the breakpoints and re-compiled the project but still this keeps happening!
I checked in the tools->options but the “Just-in–time debugging” is not marked.

Any idea?

(I use Visual Studio 6 which I installed on Vista)

Thanks a lot,
Erik

Comment: Not related to your Question but is Visual Studio 6 supported on Vista? & isn't JIT just for managed code?

Comment: You are right, it is not supported on Vista.
It's a sad story of a Legacy application that I had troubles migrating to a newer version of Visual Studio.
But it looks like at the end I won't have a choice but to do it...

Comment: @Ganesh: JIT debugging also works for native code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this helps but anyways:

Try disbaling the default debugger option. (It says Dr. Watson but it depends what you have set as the default debugger)

```
http://www.bridgetonova.com/2007/09/how-to-disableenable-windows-default.html
```

Also as per this post Visual Studio 6 is not supported on Vista. Only Visual Basic is.

```
http://www.itwriting.com/blog/167-visual-studio-6-on-vista.html
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh!
The first link did the job - now when I open the explorer and navigate somewhere the Visual Studio doesn't pop up suddenly.
However, the explorer still seems to run slowly - I don't know if it's just my feeling or could there still be some debugging process that runs in the background? (does it make sense at all ?!)

Comment: Is your PC good enough for Vista? Or is the drive slow? See your Vista rating that can be seen the control panel.
Also check in task manager if the VS Debugger the process is running.
If yes then it needs a deeper look. Else Vista has just slowed ur PC.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably re-ensure yourself that you have removed all calls to DebugBreak() and manual break-points. Also try to ensure that when you recompile you re-register everything to point to the right places (i.e. the activex pointed to by the guid in the registry is actually the latest recompile).